# Distribute VSTS build to Play store through Microsoft Appcenter

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-app-center

I have a build running in VSTS for my apps and I want to distribute these builds through Microsoft appcenter. However, I cant find a way to distribute directly into Play Store, only to distribution groups.

For distribution groups all I do is add the correct id in the release step in VSTS release task. I am using Deploy "AppName" to Visual Studio App Center task in VSTS: 
[image: Distribution group Id]
However, the different play store (or app store) distribution options does not have the same Ids.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The store id is hard to find, I came across the same problem.

Eventually I found that you can get it in App Center by going to your **App > Distribute > [Store]** and then looking in the browser's network requests. The 'latest_release' request returns an object with a property of 'distribution_stores' that will list your store connections, complete with 'id'.

[image]

There has to be a neater way to find this, surely, but this works for now.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the response from @ruffen, it appears there is indeed a neater way. There is now an App Centre api endpoint available, here: https://openapi.appcenter.ms/#/distribute/stores_list

Just look for the same id property in the response.

Comment: I got in touch with them through their help feature and found you can get the same Id by using their API. This is now documented as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/vsts-deploy

Comment: This saved me, and amazed me at the same time.  Whilst the API does look neater to use, I found it easier to just follow your original suggestion of checking out API responses, as that way I didn't need to work out how to manage the authentication steps too (which I know is certainly documented somewhere).  I'm amazed that this was so difficult to get to, given I'm setting up a connection between two Microsoft dev services.

Answer (score 6):

1. To get the distribution group id, login to app center or if you have
   already logged in, click on the “App Center” logo at the top left to
   go to the home screen.
2. On the left menu, select the Organization.
3. Under that, select “People” and then select “Distribution groups”.
4. Select the distribution group for which you need the Id.
5. Select the tool icon on the right corner. It will display the distribution
   group id right below the group name.

**Note:** You should be an admin to get the group id.